# Unable to find file "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml"

Tags: php, xml, symfony, yaml

Today I installed Symfony 2.7.9 for the first time and of course I've installed Sonata Admin (successfully). Now I'm trying to install SonataUserBundle like described [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html). But all the time I get the same error:

> Unable to find file "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml" in 
>   @SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml (which is being 
>   imported from "/Users/alex/www/Personal/startup-1/app/config/routing.yml"). Make sure 
>   the "SonataUserBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel 
>   class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path 
>   "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml" is not empty.

And YES, of course I checked **admin_ressetting.xml** and found that folder **@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing** is empty.

Here my files:

[config.yml](https://gist.github.com/madonzy/1b5fb3556484b1352736), [routing.yml](https://gist.github.com/madonzy/72c2e0d2214f972fd76d), [security.ylm](https://gist.github.com/madonzy/e6970a1fd1cc529a3ca7), [AppKernel.php](https://gist.github.com/madonzy/8e8d87d616e363e82ce0)

Also I'll note that:

1. My database contains **0** tables.
2. In folder **src/Application/Sonata** I have the only folder **UserBundle**

Comment: I just looked at the source on Github and it seems you are simply missing the file. https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/routing Were there  composer errors?

Comment: I should just add that files? When I added the only admin_resetting.xml, the other errors appeared. Maybe something wrong with installation bundle?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a real issue with the 2.2.4 version of SonataUserBundle. Indeed **admin_ressetting.xml** is missing as you can see [there](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/tree/2.2.4/Resources/config/routing).

FYI, I just posted [an issue](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/696) reporting the bug.

You can get the file [from the master branch](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml) and create it under **vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Resources/config/routing** to fix it meanwhile.

**Update** *(Apr, 28'16)*

In fact, that's not an issue but a documentation misleading (the default documentation is ahead of last release). You need to refer to the [v2.2 documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html#integrating-the-bundle-into-the-sonata-admin-bundle) if you want to use the last release, which is the 2.2.4 for now.

Answer (score -1):

If you really checked *@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing* which should be located under *vendor/* and it's empty I would recommend you to delete vendor-directory, clear composer cache (`compser clear-cache`) and run `composer install` again.

As you can see at Github the directory should not be empty and contain more files than *admin_resetting.xml*.

Comment: @SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing  was located in src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle folder

Comment: Why is it located under src/Application? Didn't you install it via composer?

Comment: I installed via composer like described [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html)

Comment: Yeah but installed packages like "php composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle --no-update" should be located under *vendor/* the bundle made by easy-extends is mainly to store entities. The configuration should be located in SonataUserBundle under *vendor/* not in ApplicationSonataUserBundle in *src/*.

Comment: Also under **vendor** folder I have **sonata-project/user-bundle/** inside ** vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Resources/config/routing** i have he following files: admin_security.xml, api.xml, sonata_change_password_1.xml, sonata_registration_1.xml, sonata_resetting_1.xml, sonata_security_1.xml. But no admin_ressetting.xml

Comment: A created the file admin_ressetting.xml manualy and now it works. But why composer didn't create it automatically?

Comment: There must be something wrong while installing dependencies. I recommend you like answered to delete vendor, clear composer cache and reinstall it via composer install.